# How do I add one to a variable in Python 3.8?

Tags: python-3.8

I have a code of:

```
x = 0

def start():
    x = x + 1
    print (str(x))
```

But, I get an error saying that I mentioned the variable more than once, so I googled it and tried:

```
x = 0

def start():
    x += x
    print (str(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to affect the *global* `x`, you should explicitly state that:

```
def start():
    global x
    x = x + 1
    print (str(x))
```

The reason you have a problem is that `x = x + 1` first creates the *local* `x` because you're assigning to it, and it's not explicitly marked global.

Then it uses that *local* `x` (it looks "upward" to find the closest scope that contains the name) to calculate `x + 1` and, because it hasn't been initialised yet, you get your error `local variable 'x' referenced before assignment` (not sure where your "mentioned more than once" comes from).

Note that this isn't a problem with something like `y = x + 1`, since the local variable created is `y` and it will therefore look upwards in scope to find the *global* `x` for the calculation.

Note further that `x += x` is not adding one, it's doubling the value. In any case, it (and the more correct `x += 1`) still suffer from the uninitialised variable issue. That's because `x += n` is just syntactic sugar for `x = x + n`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to Python and I couldn't quite remember the error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a ***global*** statement.

```
def start():
    global x
    x = x + 1
    print (str(x))
```

Why? You are trying to access a variable *outside* the function. In other words, The local variable *x* is inaccessible inside the function. Oh, and x += x doesn't add one, it doubles the number. x += 1 is just short of x = x + 1.